# Execute Oracle stored procedure in operation manager configuration

Tags: oracle, scom

I have a stored procedure with 3 parameters. I want to execute this from configuration in operation manager. I used like this :

```
begin    
saman_test.CONVERTHISTORY('$Config/JobType$','$Config/HostFQDN$','$Config/Environment$'); end;
```

but it does not work without any error.

And I used this code:

```
exec 
saman_test.CONVERTHISTORY('$Config/JobType$','$Config/HostFQDN$','$Config/Environment$')
```

but I get this error :

> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

How do I execute my procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I find the keyword for execute my procedure.

```
call
saman_test.CONVERTHISTORY('$Config/JobType$','$Config/HostFQDN$','$Config/Environment$')
```